# `new NativeEventEmitter()` requires a non-null argument , getting this while running app

Tags: ios, reactjs, xcode, react-native

When I try to run my app on xcode simulator I get bunch of these

```
`new NativeEventEmitter()` requires a non-null argument
```

I am not sure what i am doing wrong or what i changed, it works well on web version. Does anyone has faced this before ?